# How do I require the sandbox?

Tags: bazel

I don't want users to accidentally disable the sandbox by leaving user namespaces disabled in their kernel, or through other mechanisms.  I want to be able to trust their build results.  How do I force the sandbox on through flags?

(The easiest way I've found to test this is to move /bin/true somewhere else momentarily and verify that Bazel refuses to build anything)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can specify an explicit Spawn strategy instead of relying on the "pick the best available" algorithm:

`bazel build --spawn_strategy=linux-sandbox`

This will let builds fail with an error if user namespaces are not available. On macOS the name of the strategy is "darwin-sandbox".

If you're building Java code, you might also want to either enable Worker sandboxing (`--worker_sandboxing`) or disable the persistent worker feature and compile Java inside the stricter sandbox (`--strategy=Javac=linux-sandbox`).